# Meta-analysis of the meta-analysis tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-reorganization

There are [meta-analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-analysis)×654 and [meta-regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-regression)×101 tags. Meta-regression is a particular approach to meta-analysis so it's a subset tag. 90 out of 101 Qs are *also* tagged with [meta-analysis], i.e. there are almost no questions tagged with [meta-regression] only. Given that, do we really need this tag, or should it perhaps be merged into [meta-analysis] (which will only increase the question count there by 11)?

On a related note, I have recently learned that there are fixed effects models, random effects models, and mixed effects models in meta-analysis (see brief but very clear Chapter 2 in https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v036i03/v36i03.pdf). Obviously, people use our [random-effect-model], [fixed-effect-model], and [mixed-model] tags in combination with [meta-analysis], but in fact these models in meta analysis are clearly distinct from mixed models (e.g. you cannot fit them with `lmer`). Confusing! So I suggest to create tags like `[meta-analysis-fixed-effects]`, `[meta-analysis-random-effects]`, and `[meta-analysis-mixed-effects]` as synonyms of [meta-analysis].

@mdewey wrote me elsewhere that

> I do not see any pressing need for meta-analysis tagged questions to also have a random effects tag (or fixed effects for that matter)

which I think is in line with what I suggest (?).

Finally, as far as I could understand "meta-regression" is another name for "mixed effects model in meta-analysis". Which might be another reason to make it a synonym. If not, then alternatively `[meta-analysis-mixed-effects]` could point to [meta-regression].

Comment: Since meta-regression is a proper subset of meta-analysis making it a synonym is fine. By the same logic f-e, r-e and m-e meta-analysis might as well be synonyms of meta-analysis too. Or we could just delete f-e, r-e when we see them used with meta-analysis..

Comment: @mdewey I'd rather have meta-analysis synonyms for f-e, r-e, and m-e, because otherwise people will keep using other tags for this purpose.

Comment: @mdewey There is also a small [network-meta-analysis] tag with ~10 Qs but here I have no opinion at all and am fine with keeping it as is.

Comment: Although n-m-a is a subset of m-a it is sufficiently a niche area that a separate tag does seem helpful.

Comment: I would be inclined to leave [m-r] as is; someone could well want to search on that & read those specific threads as distinct from regular, old m-a. Ideally, we would get people to not feel they need to use both tags (let me know if you have a solution for that ;-). The fixed & random effects versions of m-a are more of an issue; people should not be using our standard mixed tags for those. Creating the new tags to be synonyms is a good solution here. This is a case where I'd prefer to have the tags on 1 thread & don't merge, though, so they would be more salient in the future.

Comment: @gung I have no problem with subset tags, as long as the smaller tag has a clear scope and the bigger tag has enough Qs to warrant the subsetting. So even if 100% of [m-r] Qs were tagged with [m-a], it would be fine with me. The question is rather, is "meta-regression" a clearly defined *and* useful subset? I have no experience in meta analysis, so I have no opinion. We have two users who are very active in these tags and I pinged both of them to share their opinions.

Comment: @gung Regarding synonyms, I strongly dislike keeping a synonym on 1 thread. It's cumbersome, it's against the SE guidelines, it's gaming the system, and it's not a stable solution (one edit to this thread and the full merge will happen). Also, I don't see a benefit. Ideally, this will be a part of my old plan on reorganizing fixed-effect and random-effect tags. My current thinking is to have meta-analysis-random-effect -> meta-analysis, mixed-model-random-effect -> mixed-model, econometrics-random-effect (on its own), and anova-random-effect -> anova. But let's deal with meta-analysis first...

Comment: Chiming in here based on the request by @amoeba I think the meta-regression tag is useful. I skimmed through the questions that are tagged with m-r and see some cases where it is used when it doesn't seem relevant/applicable. As for the FE/RE/ME stuff - this one is tricky. In principle, the terms *could* have the same meaning in the context of meta-analysis (and imho they should) but they have taken on bizarre interpretations/definitions in the meta-analytic context that are really confusing. So not really sure what to do about these tags when they are used for meta-analysis questions.

Comment: @Wolfgang Thanks for joining the discussion. Okay, we can keep [meta-regression]. Regarding FE/RE/ME, could you clarify what bizarre interpretations you mean? My understanding (based on your paper linked in my question here) was that all these models in meta-analytic context assume known (and heteroscedastic) error variances, unlike what happens in basically any other regression context. I guess this is not what you mean by "bizarre"?

Comment: Wolfgand and @mdewey, I tried to edit the [meta-regression] wiki excerpt, can you please make sure that it makes sense and is useful? https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/87546/revisions We could potentially cut out the 2nd sentence if you think it will be only confusing for the readers.

Comment: When I looked we have 39 with m-a + r-e-m of which 10 also have f-e-m, there are 19 with m-m of which 4 have r-e-m and 1 f-e-m. f-e on its own is rare. Interestingly m-m occurs quite often with meta-reg which is adding nothing. @Wolfgang may have more to say here but none of this surprised me.

Comment: The meta-reg excerpt looks fine but the wiki itself does not ring true to me. I will have a think unless someone gets there first.

Comment: @mdewey My current inclination based on the discussion above is to remove all f-e-m, r-e-m, and m-m from Qs with m-a (around 50 threads involved probably?) and then create three synonyms of m-a: meta-analysis-fixed-effects, meta-analysis-random-effects, meta-analysis-mixed-effects. Meta-regression can be left alone based on Wolfgang's and gung's comments (btw, by now 100% of Qs with m-r are also tagged m-a).

Comment: @mdewey (Of course not all instances of m-m need to be removed. If a question asks about "standard" mixed model vs meta-analytic mixed model then it's obviously fine to keep m-m. I would remove all f-e-m and r-e-m though because these two tags are ambiguous). It seems that there is no opposition here. Would you be willing to go through these threads?

Comment: I will have a look at them and delete all the obvious ones with f|r-effect or m-m and come back with any puzzles.

Comment: I have now deleted f-e, r-e and m-m as appropriate. I have left a couple with m-m where there did seem to be a comparison between meta-analysis and mixed-model.

Comment: @mdewey Great thanks. I've just noticed and rolled back the removal of m-m from here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116659 - isn't it explicitly using `nlme`?

Comment: Yes indeed but since it already had nlme-lme I thought mixed-model was redundant (almost). But fine with me.

Comment: @mdewey Yeah, that's this old issue of software tags... I usually prefer to have [mixed-model] tag on *every* question with [lme4-nlme], it does not make at lot of sense to me otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the discussion in comments above, my current suggestions are as follows:

1. [meta-regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-regression) stays as a distinct tag. Currently *all* questions with [meta-regression] are also tagged with [meta-analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-analysis), but it's still a useful subset tag to have.
2. We remove all instances of [fixed-effects-model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fixed-effects-model) and [random-effects-model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-effects-model) from [meta-analysis] threads. We also remove most instances of [mixed-model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-model), leaving only the ones that are really about "standard" mixed models *and* meta-analysis.
3. We  create the following three tag synonyms:

   - `[meta-analysis-fixed-effects]` $\to$ [meta-analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-analysis)
   - `[meta-analysis-random-effects]` $\to$ [meta-analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-analysis)
   - `[meta-analysis-mixed-effects]` $\to$ [meta-analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-analysis)

**Update: (2) done by @mdewey, (3) done by @gung.**